# On Python, How would you allow users to enter items on dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary and could not find how to get a user to enter a word/phrase and a definition. For example:

```
    dict = [
        { "polar": 'bear'
          "giraffe":'neck'
        }
    ]
```

So I am asking: how would you get it so users are asked to add a new word for example, 'horse' and assign it the definition of 'hay'and add it to the dictionary. So it will print like:

```
    dict = [
        { "polar": 'bear'
          "giraffe":'neck'
          "horse":'hay'
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Why do you wrap the dictionary in a list?

Comment: If that is incorrect, i apologise, I am not too great with coding, how is it supposed to be like?

Comment: well it is not *per se* incorrect, but here I don't see a reason to do that. Furthermore you better do not use a variablename like `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `input` in a loop:

```
from pprint import pprint

animals = {}
while True:
    key = input('Animal: ')
    value = input('Value: ')
    animals[key] = value
    pprint(animals)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, this is for only one input from the user.

```
dict = { "polar": 'bear' , "giraffe":'neck'}
key = input("Please enter a word: ")
item = input("Please enter a definition: ")
dict[key] = item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can here add upto 5 keys and values, example. To increase the number of user inputs you can always change the range to be higher than 5 or to reduce you can lower the range.

> polar bear, where polar will be key and bear will be value

```
d = {}
for i in range(5):
    user = input('Enter animal followed by space and its type')
    data = user.split()
    d[data[0]] = data[1]
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you created `dict` variable as list. And there is a method for dictionaries called `update()`. You can use it such as `dict[0].update({"foo", "bar"})`

Answer (score 0):

Added this version similar to above but with some looping over the input etc...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # This will store our definitions...
    words = {}

    # Will ask for new words / commands until exit...
    while True:
        word = input('What\'s your word (p: print, <enter>: exit)? >>> ')

        if word == 'p':
            print(f'Current words: {words}')
        elif word == '':
            break
        else:
            definition = input(f'Definition of {word}? >>> ')
            words[word] = definition

    print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to dict entries using `dictname[key] = value`
eg `dict7['polar'] will return 'bear'`

```
dict7 = {'polar': 'bear',
         'giraffe': 'neck'
         }

newkey = input("Please enter new dict key: ")  # get new key
newvalue = input("Please enter new dict value: ")  # get new value

dict7[newkey] = newvalue
```

Note: I'm using `dict7` rather than `dict` because it's not a good idea to use words like `list` and `dict` that python uses as keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if entered key, value is not in dict already if not then just add it :

```
dict = [
        { "polar": 'bear',
          "giraffe":'neck'
        }
    ]


keyinput=input("Enter the key")
valueinput=input("Enter value")

if keyinput not in dict:
    dict[0][keyinput]=valueinput


print(dict)
```

input:

```
Enter the key New polar
Enter value New Bear
[{'polar': 'bear', 'New polar': 'New Bear', 'giraffe': 'neck'}]
```

if i input same key , value which already exists :

```
Enter the key polar
Enter value bear
[{'giraffe': 'neck', 'polar': 'bear'}]
```